# why return Duplicate entry '2' for key 'OpenOrder.PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, sql

hi anyone tell me whats wrong in sql query ?

```
INSERT INTO  OpenOrder  
SELECT OpenOrderTemp.*
FROM OpenOrderTemp
LEFT OUTER JOIN OpenOrder OpenOrder ON OpenOrder.symbol=OpenOrderTemp.symbol 
                                    and OpenOrder.clientorderid = OpenOrderTemp.clientorderid 
                                    and OpenOrder.orderid = OpenOrderTemp.orderid   
                                    and OpenOrder.price = OpenOrderTemp.price 
WHERE OpenOrder.symbol is null;
```

my table

example data OpenOrder

```
-------------------------------------------
|symbol|orderid|clientorderid|price|etc....|
-------------------------------------------
|MDTUSD|1223156|web_121354542|42.00|
|REBUSD|1224578|web_128875666|22.00|
....
```

example data OpenOrderTemp

```
------------------------------------------
|symbol|orderid|clientorderid|price|etc.. |
------------------------------------------
|MDTUSD|1223156|web_121354542|42.00|
|REBUSD|1224578|web_128875666|22.00|
|ORNBTC|2585582|web_128545456|02.00|
....
```

Comment: You can't get that error from a `SELECT` query, only from `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: There's no point in using a table alias that's the same as the table name. Usually aliases are shortened names to make the query less verbose.

Comment: is  a  insert @Barmar the  ''' cancel my insert if you edit  you can saw

Comment: What column is the primary key of the `OpenOrder` table?

Comment: id  for both table  and for both is  autoincrement not null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have duplicate IDs between the two tables. When you use `SELECT OpenOrderTemp.*` it tries to copy the IDs from `OpenOrderTemp` to `OpenOrder`, and that will try to copy those duplicate keys.

You'll need to omit the `id` column when inserting, so you have to list all the columns explicitly.

```
INSERT INTO OpenOrder (symbol, orderid, clientorderid, price, etc...)
SELECT symbol, orderid, clientorderid, price, etc...
FROM OpenOrderTemp
LEFT OUTER JOIN OpenOrder OpenOrder ON OpenOrder.symbol=OpenOrderTemp.symbol 
                                    and OpenOrder.clientorderid = OpenOrderTemp.clientorderid 
                                    and OpenOrder.orderid = OpenOrderTemp.orderid   
                                    and OpenOrder.price = OpenOrderTemp.price 
WHERE OpenOrder.symbol is null;
```

When inserting into `OpenOrder` it will assign new IDs using auto increment.